# Visual Studio Extensibility Package not looking at correct project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vs-extensibility

I have created a new VS 2010 extensibility package.  So far, all I want to do is have the user press a button and fill a listview with the entire contents of the solution.  I have the following code:

```
EnvDTE80.DTE2 dte = (EnvDTE80.DTE2)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.
    GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.10.0");

foreach (Project project in dte.Solution.Projects)
{
    foreach(ProjectItem pi in project.ProjectItems)
    {
         listView1.Items.Add(pi.Name.ToString());
    }
}
```

This does seem to work, however, it populates the list with the contents of the solution with the package *in it* and not the experimental instance that is launched when this is run.  Am I instantiating the reference wrongly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> GetActiveObject method returns first process instance of DTE, not
>   caller DTE. (in Visual Studio SDK 2010 project on Visual Studio 2010,
>   type F5 to execure experimental hive may fail)

Look at [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/c3291548-8100-4256-85b9-10871800317a/) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/55f5d612-fea6-42a9-a3e2-c2625a7cd1b3) for more details...

Answer (score 0):

No - you need to use [`ProjectItem.SubProject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.projectitem.subproject%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to get to what you want... depending on the solution structure some recursion could be needed... for some sample code doing nicely all this see http://www.wwwlicious.com/2011/03/envdte-getting-all-projects.html